# could I achieve it to fill different colors by selecting cursor within the boundary of each concentric circles in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors, geometry, fill, color-picker

I have 3 concentric circles within inside of each other. I want to use the color picker to open when the cursor is clicked on the circle and fill color for that particular circle.

I tried pointing cursor on one of the circle and fill color, but it fills to full of the larger circle.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask]. They will help you get started in asking a question here